# ajax jquery with json not working on IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below code works perfectly on ever browser except IE.If someone could hel me in fixing this ,that would be really great!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#signup-form').submit(function(){

  //check the form is not currently submitting
  if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){

   //setup variables
   var form = $(this),
    formData = form.serialize(),
    formUrl = form.attr('action'),
    formMethod = form.attr('method'),
    responseMsg = $('#form-response');

   //add status data to form
   form.data('formstatus','submitting');

   //show response message - waiting
   responseMsg.hide()
        .addClass('response-waiting')
        .text('Please Wait...')
        .fadeIn(200);

   //send data to server for validation
   $.ajax({
    url: formUrl,
    type: formMethod,
    data: formData,
    success:function(data){

     //setup variables
     var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
      klass = '';

     //response conditional
     switch(responseData.status){
      case 'error':
       klass = 'response-error';
      break;
      case 'success':
       klass = 'response-success';
      break;
     }

     //show reponse message
     responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
      $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
          .addClass(klass)
          .text(responseData.message)
          .fadeIn(200,function(){
           //set timeout to hide response message
           setTimeout(function(){
            responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                $(this).removeClass(klass);
             form.data('formstatus','idle');
            });
           },3000)
        });
     });
    }
   });
  }

  //prevent form from submitting
  return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: So, like, when it **doesn't** work, what happens?  Did your computer explode?

Comment: Nothing happens..dont see form raising any exceptions...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var form = $(this),
var formData = form.serialize(),
var formUrl = form.attr('action'),
var formMethod = form.attr('method'),
var responseMsg = $('#form-response');
```

make a habit to use var for declaring variable.
without var sometime it working in IE

**Amit Battan**

Comment: Ok..I see something coming now , when I submit it show message display on a new page. but my editor is not accepting all 'var' for the variable .It complains missing varible name... And this is the message which thorws on a new page rather than showing on currentpage {"status":"error","message":"Enter lastname"}

Comment: IE throws following exception "Expected identifier" when I explicitly specified var.what does that mean

Comment: Can any one help out with this issue, it works fine in IE7 also why isn't it working for IE8

Comment: what exactly your problem...var will not create any  problem if it work in mozilla then sometime due to not using var it not works in IE, try use alert to trace your bug where it is exactly